# How can I use base.html like a regular template, and render to it

Tags: python, django

I have my navbar css in my base.html, and then use {% extend base.html %} to add it into my regular template. However, I want to have a login/register option in my navbar (which is in my base.html), and I want to use cookies to decide whether to put login or register in the navbar. How can I have base.html be able to request cookies, when it doesn't have a view? Also, not every webpage on my site has a view, some are a plain html with {% extend base.html %}

my base.html:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-175481126-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-175481126-1');
</script>

<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
background-color: #333;
}
li {
float: left;
border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
li a {
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
 li a:hover {
   background-color: #111;
   color: white;
   text-decoration:none;
 }

/* for buttons*/
.paging {
background-color: #333;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 8px 14px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
background-color: #111;
}

.register {
  float: right;
}

.paging {
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

/* title */

.title {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  Color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* descriptions */

.description {
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
}

/* embedd url */
.iframe-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
  height: 0;
    margin-left: auto;   /* Automatic margin from left */ 
    margin-right: auto; /* Automatic margin from right */
}
.iframe-container iframe{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* make columns */

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* you can just remove these margins all together. Just wanted to emphasize that there should be no margin left or right, to avoid overflow */
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.videos, .ads {
    flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;
}

.ads {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background-color: #c1c4c9;
    width: 25%;
}

.videos {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.image {
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.logo {
    flex-direction:; row;
    flex:; 0 0 100%;
    max-width 100%;
    justify-content:; center;
}

.banner {
/*  float: left;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

/* header */
.header {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
</style>

<html>

{% load static %}

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}"/>

<div class="logo">
<div class="header">
  <a href="/">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5Rqps7F/logo-black.png" alt="Computer Man">
</a>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="all"><a href="/">All videos</a></li>
  <li class="stam"><a href="/stam">Stam videos</a></li>
  <li class="music"><a href="/music">Music videos</a></li>
  <li class="news"><a href="/news">News videos</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="register"><a href="/register">Login/Register</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="banner">
    <text align="center">We are still developing our site, so we may not be able to update videos as often as we want</text>
</div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "_not every webpage on my site has a view_"? How do you serve the HTML then without a view?? Also you can check if a user is logged in using `request.user.is_authenticated`.

Comment: where do you keep your navbar items? in the base.html? it it hard code?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, I server some html without a view. Also, I want to decide what to put based on if they registered for an account or not, not if they are logged in.

Comment: @KIN1991 I've added my base.html to the question

Comment: @KovyJacob my question was "How do you serve the HTML then without a view?". Your comment does not answer that at all. Show your url patterns for these pages... And how will you find out whether a user has an account if they are not logged in?? It is **not possible** to magically find out if someone has an account with your site...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want to use cookies, and make a cookie when they register. Also, I haven't added in the html with no view yet, but O will be doing it shortly. There is a module for it.

Comment: @KovyJacob a cookie is not very useful for what you describe, firstly cookies are not permanent. Second what if a user simply uses another browser / device, etc. You idea is fundamentally flawed here.

Answer (score 0):

Put the navbar in a separate file. Probably call it `_nav.html`.

And then in the `base.html` file, reference the navbar at the beginning of the body tag-

```
<body>
{% include '_nav.html' %}
.....
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

This way you keep your `base.html` file cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you avoid to keep logic like building navigation in your template. Good practice is building navigation items in a context_processor, and display them in the template.

So at first you need to create context_processor, you may create site_navigation.py file in the same fold which contains the settings.py file.

Structure example:

```
project/
    ...
    settings.py
    site_navigation.py
    ...
```

Then you need make function (in the site_navigation.py file, which you created before), which will return items of your navigation, in this function you  also may make logic which will append some special items for authorized users:

```
def navbar(request):
    navbar_items = [
        {'name': 'Home', 'link': '/'},
        {'name': 'Link One', 'link': '/link-one'},
        {'name': 'Link two', 'link': '/link-two'}
    ]

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        navbar_items.append({'name': 'Link three', 'link': '/link-three'})

    return {
        'navbar_items': navbar_items
    }
```

Then you should add new context processor in your settings file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'project.site_navigation.navbar'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Finally need to display your navbar items in your base.html file:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in navbar_items %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```